# Is the set of vanishing $k$ derivatives of smooth functions in a null set dense in $W^{1,p}$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fake-proofs

Let $\Omega$ be an open set with compact closure denoted by $\overline{\Omega}$  and a null set $N\subset\Omega$   with respect the Lebesgue measure.

Then consider the two sets

- $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ (smooth functions in $\overline{\Omega}$).
- $V=\{\psi\in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega}/N) \text{ with } \psi=\psi_{a_{1}}=...=\psi_{a_{1}...a_{k}}=0 \text{ in }  N  \} \cup \{\psi\in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega}) \text{ with } \psi=\psi_{a_{1}...a_{k}}=0 \text{ in }  N  \}$

So $V$ is the set of all  $\phi\in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ functions where the value of $\phi$ and and its first $k$ derivatives is change to be $0$ at $N$.

Now is $V$ dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$?

I think it is for the following reason:

Consider $\phi\in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ then $\phi\in W^{k,p}$. Now this $\phi$ is in the same class as $\phi_{n}$ which is just $\phi$ everywhere except possibly at $N$.

So "according to" the $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ space $\phi_{n}$ is $\phi$ in  $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$. And then we know that the class of $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

This conclude the argument as we have prove that that  $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})\subset V$ as classes in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$

Why is this argument incorrect?

Comment: If $N=\partial \Omega$ and $\Omega$ is a smooth domain, then $V\subset W^{k,p}_0(\Omega)$, in particular such functions can't be dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Fair enough, I noted that now. I will correct that in the question.

Comment: The issue is not the boundary, but that Sobolev functions have traces on smooth submanifolds of the domain. For instance take $\Omega$ to be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and take $N=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \{ 0\}$, then $V$ is contained in the set of Sobolev functions with zero trace on $N$, but then the constant function $1$ can't be approximated with these functions.

Comment: $N$ could be dense in $\Omega$, in which case any $C^\infty$ function whose derivatives vanish on $N$ would have to be constant.

Comment: Even worse, for $p > n$ we would expect a Holder modulus of continuity controlled by the norm of the gradient when $k \geq 1$, so vanishing at a point immediately breaks density.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you for your comment. Would you mind clarifying for me why the constant function $1$ is not the same as the function $1$ everywhere but $N$ which is in $V$?

Comment: I suppose ultimately the problem has to do with how you describe the behavior of a function on a null set. For example, when $p > n$ it is technically true that the Soboleve functions are defined almost everywhere, but indeed they have continuous representatives of the classes so it is silly to describe the pointwise or nullset behaviour in any way except by the continuous representative.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the imprecision. I am interested in the case p<n.

Comment: So in the strictest sense it is dense? I am confused about exactly how the trace and the freedom of null set are linked to each other.My main motivation for this question is this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0101018 pg 5. They claim the set $V_{0}$ is dense in $W^{1,2}$

Answer (score 1):

The argument is incorrect.

Suppose $\phi \in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega}) \subset W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.  As you say, we can define a function
$$\phi_n(x) = \begin{cases} \phi(x), & x \notin N \\ 0, & x \in N \end{cases}$$
Then $\phi_n$ is a function that vanishes on $N$ and is almost everywhere equal to $\phi$.  However, $\phi_n$ typically will not be $C^\infty$, so it is not an element of your set $V$, which you specifically defined to consist only of $C^\infty$ functions.  Generally, if you modify a continuous function on a null set, it will no longer be continuous.  (A null set has a dense complement, so if $\phi$ and $\phi_n$ are both continuous and are equal on $N^c$, they must also be equal on $N$.)

For an explicit counterexample, let $n=1$, $p=1$, $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $N = \Omega \cap \mathbb{Q}$.  If $\phi \in C^\infty$ and $\phi'$ vanishes on $N$ then $\phi$ is constant.  Likewise if $\phi$ vanishes on $N$ then $\phi = 0$.  So $V$ only contains the constants, or more properly, $V$ consists of those equivalence classes which contain a constant function.  For a function to be in one of the equivalence classes in $V$, it must be almost everywhere equal to a constant.  This is a closed subset of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ and is certainly not dense.

Comment: Thank for your answer. However,I am allowing functions to be not smooth at $N$. Also can something be said in the case $N$ is a submanifold for example instead of dense?